# javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java

Estou com o seguinte problema no desenvolvimento da autenticação de usuário e senha da minha aplicação:

```
jun 30, 2016 8:49:27 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
ADVERTÊNCIA: #{LoginMB.efetuaLogin}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;
javax.faces.FacesException: #{LoginMB.efetuaLogin}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;
    at br.com.arena.dao.PessoaDAO.existe(PessoaDAO.java:82)
    at br.com.arena.controller.LoginBean.efetuaLogin(LoginBean.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 29 more

jun 30, 2016 8:49:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/arena] threw exception [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljavax/persistence/TypedQuery;
    at br.com.arena.dao.PessoaDAO.existe(PessoaDAO.java:82)
    at br.com.arena.controller.LoginBean.efetuaLogin(LoginBean.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Acredito que o problema esteja no metodo existir da minha classe PessoaDAO:

```
public boolean existe(Pessoa pessoa) {

    String consulta = "select u from Usuario u where u.email = :pEmail and u.senha = :pSenha";
    TypedQuery<Pessoa> query=getEm().createQuery(consulta,Pessoa.class);
 // TypedQuery<Pessoa> query = em.createQuery("select u from Usuario u where u.email = :pEmail and u.senha = :pSenha",Pessoa.class);

    query.setParameter("pEmail", pessoa.getNomeUsuario());
    query.setParameter("pSenha", pessoa.getSenhaUsuario());

    Pessoa resultado = query.getSingleResult();

    return resultado != null;
}
```

Ele e chamado da seguinte forma pela LoginBean:

```
public String efetuaLogin() {
    System.out.println("Fazendo login do usuário "
            + this.pessoa.getNomeUsuario());

    boolean existe = new PessoaDAO().existe(this.pessoa);

    if (existe) {
        return "livro?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    return null;
}
```

Que por sua vez e chamado da executado da seguinte forma no Login.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>

<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="titulo">
    Login - Faça seu Login
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <h:form>
                <p:messages id="messages" />
              <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel for="nomeUsuario" value="Nome Usuário:" />
                    <p:inputText id="nomeUsuario" value="#{LoginMB.pessoa.nomeUsuario}" />

                    <p:outputLabel for="senha" value="Senha:" />
                    <p:password id="senha" value="#{LoginMB.pessoa.senhaUsuario}" />

                    <p:commandButton value="Enviar" icon="ui-icon-star" action="#{LoginMB.efetuaLogin}" ajax="false">
                    </p:commandButton>

              </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente colocar um try catch - Acredito que exteja ocorrendo um

> javax.persistence.NoResultException:

```
public boolean existe(Pessoa pessoa) {
     try{   
       String consulta = 
         "select u from Usuario u where u.email = :pEmail and u.senha = :pSenha";
       TypedQuery<Pessoa> query= getEm().createQuery(consulta,Pessoa.class);
       query.setParameter("pEmail", pessoa.getNomeUsuario());
       query.setParameter("pSenha", pessoa.getSenhaUsuario());
       Pessoa resultado = query.getSingleResult();
       return resultado != null;
     } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.printf("\n Erro %s \n" , e);
        return false; 
     }
}
```